# Search using Unix's split|grep|cat vs Hadoop

Tags: unix, hadoop

Why would I use hadoop to search string in a multiple large files instead of using the out of the box unix tools like split, grep and cat?

Thanks
Ashish

Answer (score 0):

Hadoop is designed to search multiple files and combine the results. The other tools mentioned will not do that (without a lot of work).  In particular, since Hadoop does this (across multiple servers), in *parallel*, that would mean that the "lot of work" would have to be done in some language which supports parallelism.  Python could be used for ad hoc prototypes, but likely not tools comparable to split, grep and cat such as bash (unless you reduce the requirements drastically).